# Layer not completely drawing in ArcGIS published service

Tags: arcgis-server, proximity, arcgis-rest-api, geoserver-rest-api, rest

I am publishing a service and one of my polygon feature layers is not completely drawing when viewing the published data through ArcGIS REST API. All features within this feature class are drawing with the exception of one. All shapefile fields are visible. Please refer to the screenshots below...

ArcMap:

[image: ArcMap:]

REST Service:

[image: REST Service:]

Comment: Did you publish by letting the data be uploaded, or by accessing a published folder?  Since you reference a shapefile, is the data in shapefile format? (This is not as obvious a question as it may seem, at times.). Have you verified that the source layer does not have any topology errors?  Have you tried copying to file geodatabase and republishing?

Comment: The data is currently in a .gdb. The shp fields are visible within the feature class. Data was uploaded to a company server and service was published to previously published to folder. I hope that this answers your questions and thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Server and the ArcGIS REST API?  If so can you mention that explicitly, and tag them, please?

Comment: The meaning of "shp fields" is unclear. Do you have fields with "shp" in them in your file geodatabase tables?  Have you validated the topology of the source feature class?

Comment: The shp fields are shp_length, shp_area and Shape. I also have the Objectid field turned on for this feature class.

I am using the ArcGIS REST API.

I am attempting to validate topology but the tool but when adding my feature class the tool tell sme that 'one or more dropped items were invalid and will not be added to the control.'
I have not defined topology for this layer.

Comment: How are you publishing your service?  Is it an ArcGIS Server Map Service, or something else?

Comment: It is an ArcGIS Map Service

Comment: All the features in the feature class are present in arcmap but when i publish the service the feature above does not display in the REST API.

Comment: Check Geometry and/or Repair Geometry in Data Management

Comment: I repaired geometry and the issue is still persisting.

Comment: Does anyone think that assigning a topology would help? Does topology only need to be assigned to feature datasets?

Comment: I have rebuilt the feature class by creating a new polygon feature, adding all relevant fields, loading the data from my old feature class, and going through the steps of republishing. Unfortunately the issue is still persisting.

Comment: I have rebuilt the feature class from scratch, imported the old values into the feature class, and republished. I have checked and repaired geometry on this feature class. I am still encountering the same issue.

Comment: To clarify... the attributes for the missing feature are there, but the feature isn't rendering?

Comment: The attributes are missing for the feature. The feature is also not rendering.

Comment: Has anyone ever seen this issue before? The REST is behaving as if there is a definition query on the data.